# Facing An Issue to share a message using LinkedIn API in my Iphone Application

Tags: objective-c, ios5, linkedin-api

i am developing an iphone app, In that app i am using LinkedIn Integration For Updating My status...But I'am unable to Update My Status..Any Help will be Appreciated.

Thanks In Advance
Pandu1251

```
- (IBAction)postButton_TouchUp:(UIButton *)sender
```

{
    [statusTextView resignFirstResponder];

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"];
OAMutableURLRequest *request = 
[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                consumer:oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                   token:oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                callback:NO
                       signatureProvider:nil];

NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [[NSDictionary alloc] 
                         initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"anyone",@"code",nil], @"visibility", 
                        statusTextView.text, @"comment", nil];
 NSLog(@"statusTextView.text is---%@",statusTextView.text);

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];

NSLog(@"updateString is---%@",updateString);
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request prepare];
[request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];

OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
delegate:self
didFinishSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish:)
didFailSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:)];    
[request release];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to check for the parameters like consumer and access token etc.

or you can test it in console

https://apigee.com/console/linkedin

Have you seen this: http://www.whitneyland.com/2011/03/iphone-oauth.html

or this:

https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

They should help you get started on iOS

Comment: Every thing is fine in my project..As u said i checked my consumer and access token..i am getting my linkedIn profile details also..but i am unable so share my status..